# Laptop connection to monitor via HDMI port not working on 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, hdmi

I have been using Ubuntu for past 2 years. Initially it was Ubuntu 16.04. A few months ago I upgraded to 18.04. Today when I tried to connect my laptop through HDMI port it's not working. I have only a HDMI port in my laptop, no VGA port. I have already tried to reconfigure lightdm and gdm3, but they are not working.

Can anybody suggest a solution? It's very urgent. I don't want go back to Windows. Somebody please help me to clear this bug. There is no such option to change the screen mirroring in the settings which I have seen in some videos while searching solution for this.

Comment: Graphics card and driver version, if installed by you?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the computer while the HDMI cable is not plugged in, then plug it in.

Comment: Then also it's not working . There is no such option for multiple monitor

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a ThinkPad 13. In my case the solution was to **update the BIOS** (that happened to be 2 years old). Maybe a kernel update was dependant on BIOS changes...